# Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. Use writeConcern instead

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback4

I am using mongodb with loopback and on successful connection I am getting below warning

```
Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. Use writeConcern instead.
```

**loopback version: 5.5.0**

How to get rid of this? Kindly help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this warning was introduced in Mongo Driver [v3.6.4](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/v3.6.4/lib/write_concern.js) so the basis solution will be to down grade to v3.6.3. There is a PR that try to stop the warning outputs, and also a report on the Jira for the Node Driver. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3114

**Update:**
The problem have been fixed with the version 3.6.5

Comment: Thanks... So warning will be removed the next mongodb version. Right?

Comment: @Profer The problem should be fixed, i will keep this post updated about it.

Comment: I see this same exact warning suddenly popping out of no where

Comment: Hey how to update to version 3.6.5? Still showing me the latest version is 3.6.4.

Comment: No matching version found for mongodb@3.6.5

Comment: I have to apologize to everyone, the fix will be available when they released 3.6.5 https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/8bd9777b0aedd56b81675c3e79fae63432319982

Comment: i updated to 3.6.5 but problem is still there

Comment: @BasitMinhas There is a probability that this warning comes from some module/package that still uses an old version of the MongoDB driver and not from your code.

Answer (score 5):

Pass the following options

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true 
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Dear @Unpredict2ble please answer questions with more details. Thanks!